# Why am I getting "you may have ambiguous routes" for a rails controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, formtastic

I am having trouble with a semantic form for one of my models. The relevant models are

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :series
  ...
end

class Series < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  ...
end
```

When I visit `/series/new` in a browser, I get the error:

```
 series_url failed to generate from {:controller=>"series", :action=>"show"} - you may have ambiguous routes, or you may need to supply additional parameters for this route.  content_url has the following required parameters: ["series", :id] - are they all satisfied?
```

EDIT: I have run `rake routes | grep series | grep new` to look for conflicting routes, and there are none, here is the output:

```
new_series_event GET /series/:series_id/events/new(.:format) {:controller=>"events", :action=>"new"} 
new_series       GET /series/new(.:format) {:controller=>"series", :action=>"new"}
```

The template corresponding to the `/series/new` renders the following partial:

```
<% semantic_form_for(@series) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <% f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :uri, :label => "URL of the Series", :hint => "For example, use 'tes' for 'Transportation Education Series'. It will appear as http://events.kittelson.com/tes"    <%= f.input :description %>
    <%= f.input :contact, :label => "Contact email" %>
    <%= f.input :color, :label => "Pick a dark color" %>
  <% end %>
  <% f.buttons do %>
    <%= f.commit_button %>
    <%= link_to "or cancel", :back %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Where the `@series` object is defined in the controller as `Series.new`.

What I don't understand is how this relates to routing, I ran `rake routes` and there is only one controller action mapped to `/series/new`.

Here is the part of `config/routes.rb` that relates to these models:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :series, :has_many => :events
  map.resources :events, :has_many  => :rsvps
end
```

What could be causing this routing error?

Comment: Have you run something like `rake routes | grep series | grep new` to look for conflicting routes?

Comment: Yes, there are no conflicting routes: `new_series_event GET /series/:series_id/events/new(.:format) {:controller=>"events", :action=>"new"}
new_series GET    /series/new(.:format)                        {:controller=>"series", :action=>"new"}`

Comment: I have added the info to the question, it is near the beginning, under "EDIT".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a hunch. You might be confusing Rail's inflector. Maybe it should be `belongs_to serial` instead of `belongs_to series`?

You see, normally we would write `belongs_to user` rather than `users`. So you might want to try that out.

Comment: Good idea, but that's not it, the inflector maps "serial" to "serials", and "series" to "series" as plurals.

Comment: Actually, your hunch was right. [This article](http://somethinglearned.com/articles/2007/03/19/how-to-uncountable-names-in-restful-routes) suggested using the `:singular` option in config.routes to change make the singular version a distinct word. That worked, it got rid of the 'ambiguous routes' error.

Comment: Yay! Didnt know about the singular option before. Thanks!